# python string as hex terminated with null

Tags: python, python-3.x

I receive strings in their hex format, i.e. `s = "0x0ff"` or `s = "0fd"`
how can I check whether the above type of strings are null terminated or not? thanks!

Comment: `0x0ff` is 1 1/2 byte. I hope you get whole bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
s[-2:] == "00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you care wether python strings are null terminated?

If you want to check wether the strings start by "0x" you can just use

```
x.startswith("0x")
```

as x cannot be located anywhere else in a hexstring.